# Como listar todos os posts de uma categoria em WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Eu tenho um site feito em Wordpress aonde eu vejo as postagens dele no site, ok?

Os links funcionam, porém eu tenho uma categoria que chama "DICAS".

Na página `dominio.com/dicas` os posts da categoria dicas não abrem. Como fazer isso? Lembrando que um post na URL `dominio.com/dicas/meu-post-aqui` funciona!

Porém eu quero que o link `dominio.com/dicas` mostre apenas posts da categoria dicas. Não sei como fazer.

Então, gostaria de fazer uma página onde listasse todos os posts de uma determinada categoria. Não tenho nenhuma página no `wp-admin`, apenas categorias.

Comment: A pergunta não é sobre programação, mas acredito que possamos aceitar essas perguntas, até por que perguntas que passam muito mais longe que essa já foram muito bem aceitas

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, que perguntas ? Leve-as ao meta.

Answer (score 1):

O endereço para listar todos os posts de uma categoria é `www.example.com/category/dicas`, porém não é muito recomendado remover a base `/category/` das URLs. Por exemplo, uma categoria `wp-admin` pode bloquear o acesso ao painel administrativo; e outros conflitos podem ocorrer quando o site tem muitos posts/páginas e a estrutura de links permanentes está definida como `/%postname%/`. Use o plugin [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) para verificar possíveis conflitos (o plugin não é atualizado há mais de dois anos, mas isso não é problema, o autor é um craque).

Se você usa o plugin WordPress SEO by Yoast, ele possui essa funcionalidade:

[image]

O plugin [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) costuma ser recomendado também.

Answer (score 0):

Veja esse plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/. Acho que resolve para o que precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção, mas talvez não tão boa seria você criar na administração a Página Dicas, e depois criava o arquivo page-dicas.php onde você poderia fazer sua WP_Query passando como argumento a category_name = dicas.